# Running a code from another project in android

Tags: java, android, package

I wanted to ask, is there any way to run a code from another project that's imported in my android application?

[image]

the method I want to run in my app:

```
public void setMarkerOnScroll(int i, int j) {

}
```

the class I want to call the `setMarkerOnScroll` method in it witch is in another project:

```
@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {


}
```

Comment: properly explain your problem with example

Comment: @SinaMN75 use that imported code  as a library to your project.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes that your `setMarkerOnScroll()` method lives in the `expanding-collection` module, and you want to call this method within the `app` module.

So long as all the modules exist within the same project, each module can have a dependency on one or more other modules in this project. In your example, you want to use code from `expanding-collection` within your `app` module, so within the `dependencies {}` section of app's `build.gradle` file, add the following:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation project(':expanding-collection')
    ...
}
```

Any public classes from `expanding-collection` module should now be visible within your `app` module.

Comment: If my assumptions are wrong, then please update your question to show where `setMarkerOnScroll()`  and `onPageScrolled()` are located.